# Virtual guest: Unknown host www.google.com

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, dns

I have Debian 8.6 installed on a virtual guest running in VirtualBox.

The network adapter setting is set to **Bridged Adapter** so that I can access the guest from my LAN.

I get an IP(`192.168.1.150`) from DHCP server.
`resolv.conf` contains the following:

```
domain mydomain.local
search mydomain.local
nameserver 10.17.5.45
```

Nameserver is offsite, but it should work because I have another guest running CentOS and it can ping www.google.com, but not Debian.

Tried commenting out `# domain` and `# search` and setting nameserver to `8.8.8.8`, but that didn't resolve the issue. I can't ping the nameserver, but can ping 192.168.1.0/24 network from the guest. LAN client(including VM host) can ping nameserver no problem.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you ping your dhcp assignated gateway ?

Comment: @RemyGrandin No. 100% packet loss if I try to ping default gateway which is also DHCP. Same if I ping 8.8.8.8. But I can ping other devices on 192.168.1.X/24

Comment: I can also ping from VM host to VM guest.

Comment: If I change Network adapter to NAT then I get 10.0.X.X DHCP IP and can ping everything including the Internet and 192.168.1.X network, but I can't reach the guest from my host.

Comment: Your problem come from here, if you can't comunicate with the gateway, you can't access other network (including the internet). As your others VM works, the problem seem to come from this machine configuration. Can you check your iptables on your debian to ensure there is no rule blocking your trafic ?

Comment: @RemyGrandin I'm haven't worked with iptables before, but this is the pastebin of `iptables --list`: http://hastebin.com/oyaxaciriz.sql

Comment: I tried "disabling" iptables from this forum post, but I still can't ping outside or default gateway: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=112759